# my code not working (http Get) in android

Tags: android, http

i want to load a web page from a site and display its source on edittext , like a login , i send the login info to site and if site returns "ok" , i go to next form , but its not working , its showing emepty response :

checkout my code :

```
     package com.arash.rz.webtar;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public  class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> {

    public String SendReuqest(String command,String variables)
    {
        String response = null;
        String url="api.php?cmd="+command+"&varz="+variables;
        return response;
    }
    public void MessageBox(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        final Button btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button btnregister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final EditText txtemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText txtepass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        btnlogin.setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                readWebpage(v);
                }
              // Perform action on click
          }
          );


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }







    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }










     private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

         @Override

         protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                String response = "";

                for (String url : urls) {

                      DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                      try {

                             HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);

                             InputStream content =
                                          execute.getEntity().getContent();



                             BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(

                                           new InputStreamReader(content));

                             String s = "";

                             while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                                    response += s;

                             }

                      } catch (Exception e) {

                             e.printStackTrace();

                      }

                }

                return response;

         }



         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                //textView.setText(result);
                MessageBox("Returned:"+result);
                EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                ed.setText(result);

         }

  }



  public void readWebpage(View view) {

         DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();

         task.execute(new String[] { "http://127.0.0.1" });



  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fiddler tool to traces the network activities. It will show the traces of your request and response got from the server. By llooking at the fiddler, you can confirm the issue is on the Client or the Server.
Thanks,